# label color for selected row in NSTableview

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I subclassed `NSTableRowView` in view-based `NSTableView` to change the selection color to a lighter blue instead of the default one.

Unfortunately when I select the row the color of the labels and textfields inside my custom cell turns white and it's not readable.

How can I prevent text from changing color on selection?

Solution Found:

All I had to do is to implement `-setBackgroundStyle:` in my custom `NSTableCellView` and there call the `setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLight` on the `NSCell` of all the controls I want to keep dark on selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you change the selection color? This sounds like it could have been caused by you adding a subview or sublayer (perhaps to cell.selectedBackgroundView?) on top of the existing layers. If you have any insertSublayer or subView calls, make sure you are doing them atIndex:0.

Comment: I subclassed NSTableRowView and override drawSelectionInRect:. I don't use layers

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [make a custom NSCell](http://comelearncocoawithme.blogspot.com/2011/09/custom-cells-in-nstableview-part-1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems to go in the right direction although I have to admit I don't fully understand how to apply that method to my view-based table view. I'm already using a custom subclass of NSTableCellView.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.

All I had to do is to implement -setBackgroundStyle: in my custom NSTableCellView and there call the setBackgroundStyle:NSBackgroundStyleLight on the NSCell of all the controls I want to keep dark on selection.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out--you should edit your original question to show the solution you found, so that the next person with this issue can find the answer right off the bat!